# How do I get a changing value in a http GET request?

Tags: javascript, html, get

I am trying to obtain the value of a html input element which changes value when buttons are pressed or a value has been typed. Initially it is given a default value of 1.

```
<input type="text" name="list_quantity" value="1" id="count1">
```

Below is what I have included in the http GET request in an attempt to get the value

```
<input type="hidden" name="bought" value=document.getElementById("count1").value; />
```

In the resulting url this is the relevant parameter 
'&bought=document.getElementById%28"count1"%29.value%3B'

[image]

Comment: Is the value sent to the server?

Comment: If the `list_quantity` input's value is successfully changing, why can't you just send that to the server instead of attempting to copy it to another input?

Comment: The GET request is part of a form which occurs when a button is pressed in a different table column to the    list_quantity    . I'm not sure how to just obtain the value rather than copying it into another input

Comment: Server knows and client shows. Never trust the client for more than showing

Answer (score 1):

Is this?

```js
let c1 = document.querySelector("#count1");
let c2 = document.querySelector("#count2");

c1.onchange = function(){
  c2.type = "text";
  c2.value = c1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="list_quantity" value="1" id="count1">
<input type="hidden" name="bought" id="count2"/>
```

Or, with `onkeyup`

```js
let c1 = document.querySelector("#count1");
let c2 = document.querySelector("#count2");

c1.onkeyup = function(){
  c2.type = "text";
  c2.value = c1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="list_quantity" value="1" id="count1">
<input type="hidden" name="bought" id="count2"/>
```

Comment: Woudn't you need to assign a value for the 2nd input?

Comment: how? I don't understand?

Comment: I've uploaded a pic of the current url which I receive when implementing your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```js
function change(){
        document.getElementById('bought').value = document.getElementById('count1').value;
    }
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="bought" id="bought" />
<input onchange="change()" type="text" name="list_quantity" value="1" id="count1">
```

Comment: Still no value is being retrieved